# 403 Forbidden error when accessing website using Ubuntu

Tags: browser, websites

I'm trying to access the website www.spea.pt (Portuguese Society for the Study of Birds).
When I access the website from Arch Linux (or from my android phone) everything works. However when doing so using Ubuntu (18.04, 20.04, Kubuntu 21.10, or even my Ubuntu touch phone) I always get this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This occurs regardless of the used browser. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is not working? Is there maybe some block list built into Ubuntu?

Comment: I can confirm this happens also in Ubuntu 21.10 but only with Firefox. Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge open the website correctly.

Comment: I had only tried Chromium and "Web". Both these browsers must have "ubuntu" in their user agent string. Google chrome and MS Edge must have a different user agent string?

Comment: There are 34 answers in [this Q&A from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) to look through/

Comment: Thank you for trying to help @24601, but the link you provided is for host side solutions, whereas I was looking for a client side solution since I have no control over the SPEA website.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like simply changing the browser agent string solves the issue. Replacing the word "ubuntu" with "linux" suffices.
I'll try to contact the website owner since this looks more like a website issue than an Ubuntu issue.